# Are rechargeable li-ion considered primary batteries if charging is not available on the device?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, compliance, medical

We are designing a one time use medical device which we would like to power using a li-ion pack that would be charged only once at the time of manufacture.

For the purposes of compliance (IEC 60601) we would prefer the batteries to be considered primaries so that we would only need overcurrent protection (fuse) and not need a charging protection circuit. There are also fewer testing requirements for primary vs secondary batteries making it the more attractive option as well.

In our use case, would these batteries be considered primary or secondary?

Another way to ask it would be (for compliance purposes:) Is the primary or secondary designation determined based upon how they are used within a device or by the battery chemistry / construction?

Comment: Why Li/Ion specifically? Is there a space constraint?

Comment: Lundin - Specifically, cost / current - originally we were considering a CR-2 based battery pack but it was about four times the cost of li-ion. Additionally the device only needs to run for about 1.5 ~ 4 seconds to drive a motor and in that time with a load of 2~4A the CR-2s voltage would vary by a little over a volt whereas the li-ion pack's voltage varies by about half a volt so the motor's speed is more consistent with li-ion.

Comment: Have you considered a battery with smaller current in combination with a supercap?
I guess for your application something around 4F could work. That way you could reduce voltage-drop substantially.

Comment: All other considerations aside, rechargeable batteries generally have a shorter shelf-life than primary cells.  The sefl-discharge rate is much higher for rechargeable cells.  If shelf-life is a consideration, you'll want to avoid rechargeable cells.

Comment: CR2s are designed for low current applications.  The slightly larger form factors (e.g. 14500/AA,  3.6V) should be able to drive more current as well as having a bit of headroom on the voltage

Comment: Ordinary alkaline primary cells have quite good pulse current capacity, so they are an alternative worth considering. Also less trouble shipping them compared to lithium primary/secondary cells. The 50 joule pulse load is also within range of supercapacitors, though it would be physically large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard in question, IEC 60601-1 refers to two other standards:

> Primary lithium batteries shall comply with the requirements of IEC 60086-4. Secondary
> lithium batteries shall comply with the requirements of IEC 62133.

These standards then contain further definitions:

**IEC 60086**: *"primary (cell or battery): cell or battery that is not designed to be electrically recharged"*

**IEC 62133**: *"secondary cell: basic manufactured unit providing a source of electrical energy by direct conversion of
chemical energy, that consists of electrodes, separators, electrolyte, container and terminals,
and that is designed to be charged electrically"*

The lithium-ion cells that you use have been designed to be charged, even if you are not charging them. Thus they are secondary cells and IEC 62133 applies.

Regarding the possible workaround of adding a diode to a battery pack to prevent it from being charged, it doesn't appear to matter as it is still composed of secondary cells:

**IEC 62133**: *"secondary battery:
assembly of secondary cell(s) ready for use as a source of electrical energy characterized by
its voltage, size, terminal arrangement, capacity and rate capability"*

I don't think IEC 62133 directly requires a charging protection circuit. Instead it has specific requirements to the charging process. I haven't gone through them all, but generally they seem to take the form of "under conditions X, charge until charge current is below Y" or "for Y hours". It may be that with a designed charging current of 0, you could get an easy pass on most of the tests.

That said, including a protection circuit is still a good idea. Over-discharging Li-Ion cells can cause safety issues, even though they usually only become critical during recharging. And depending on your circuit, there might be a risk of leakage currents from external connectors accidentally charging the battery.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how it relates to the standards according to your compliance needs, but I think rechargeable lithium batteries still are classified as rechargeable lithium-ion batteries, even if you omit the charging circuitry.

Just look at any battery powered power tool; they have a separate charger so the pack and power tool themselves don't charge the pack.

If you do use lithium-ion batteries, they still act like lithium-ion batteries, you need overcurrent protection not because of charging at too high current, but also from a faulty or damaged device short circuiting the battery.

Then there's the aspect of wasting precious resources making rechargeable lithium-ion batteries which are used once and disposed. Lithium is an expensive metal that should be recycled, and the medical device anyway is considered e-waste which should anyway be recycled.

The final aspect is that rechargeable lithium-ion batteries don't work the way you might think. They lose charge over time by self-discharging, so they are rarely useful in a device that is fully charged at factory and sold later. You can't really stock these kinds of items. Rechargeable lithium-ion batteries are best stored at about half capacity when not used.

And in any case, lithium-ion batteries are dangerous when misused, if a cell gets damaged, it may explode or start a fire, so depending on what kind of medical device you are thinking, it may not be a great idea of having a disposable one-time use device with rechargeable lithium-ion battery in it, for many reasons, even if it was considered as a primary battery by compliance lab if there is no charging feature.

Comment: With this product there is a considerable amount of e-waste, but the medical industry prefers one time use disposable tools and it's what the customer wants. There are competing devices which are not one time use and therefore incorporate more robust construction to stand up to repeated uses and repeated sterilization cycles but much more expensive. 

If you've ever seen old re-usable hypodermic needles they were made of glass and metal where as today for most applications they are one time use, mostly plastic, and disposable which does produce a lot of waste but safer and cheaper.

Comment: @IsabellaLindquist I also see that point of view. Now, if your device is disposable, could it simply have a connector with cable to an external power supply, either mains brick or "power bank"?

Comment: @Justme Sounds like potentially a real can of worms. With a built-in primary battery, all you do is print an expiration date on the sealed package and all the rest is trivial for the customer (they already track the expiration of just about anything, so this just another item that is either "guaranteed ready to use" or "useless trash" depending on a simple date check). With external power supply, they need to track the expiration, make sure the batteries are always sufficiently charged, test them periodically, there needs to be a way to ensure that the connector is reliable (certified), etc.

Comment: Regarding precious resources, do you have any data to illustrate the resources needed to make a single-use Li-ion vs an equivalent (lithium?) primary cell? By the way, sad as it is, any disposable device that came into contact with a patient becomes infectious/biohazard waste and thus can't be feasibly recycled; incineration is often the only option. The staggering amount of waste is just a fact of life of the healthcare industry and it is currently the price we pay for safety.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are secondary cells, regardless of their use.

Consider instead lithium cells (primary). For example, lithium metal coin cells, or lithium thionyl chloride cells.

Comment: Do you have a reference to cite that the standard considers them always secondary cells, even if it is technically impossible to charge them? (Let's say the battery has a built-in diode or a more complicated protection circuit that completely prevents charging.)

Comment: Kindly refer to @jpa 's excellent answer.

Comment: Yes, the cells are secondary of course, but does that automatically mean the battery composed of them is too? That is what the question is about and that is not answered by this answer. battery != cell

Comment: > battery != cell -- Yes, absolutely. That is a differentiation that I am very careful to make at ever occasion.